# Unable to open BCP host data-file with AzureDB

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I'm trying to load a simple file with a single column from my local machine into my database which is located on Azure.
Both file and folder are set with read/write permissions to EVERYONE but it still fails.
Im running the following command:

```
bcp dbo.table in "C:\test_file.txt" -U"User" -P"Password" -S"tcp:AzureDB.database.windows.net" -d"database_db" -e"error.log"
```

Which results in the following error:

```
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Unable to open BCP host data-file
```

Since this service is running on a external network, I'm unable to give Azure permissions on this folder. Is there anything else I can do?

EDIT:

Following @Tibor Karaszi tips, I ran the DIR command and turns out AzureDB was reading "test_file.txt" as "test_file.txt.txt". I tried a different file format and it worked out just fine.

Comment: Azure doesn't read the file, you do. I.e. the file is on the local machine and bcp.exe is reading the file (your windows account). Please add the full error message to the post.

Comment: Error message added, though its a very brief and common one.

Comment: Are you running this from a Windows Service or scheduled task, or are you running it manually directly from the command line?

Comment: Along with Charlieface's comment: Can you open a command prompt and in there execute that BCP command. No bat file, schedulers etc. And also from that same command prompt do a DIR of the folder. One comment is that the root folder is rarely a good choice (could be some protection in place), try a subfolder to the root.